# Creating multiindex from 2 rows with duplicated columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have an excel file that I read with pandas and convert to a dataframe. Here is a sample of the dataframe:

```
|               | salads_count | salads_count | salads_count | carrot_counts | carrot_counts | carrot_counts |
|---------------|--------------|--------------|--------------|---------------|---------------|---------------|
|               | 01.2016      | 02.2016      | 03.2016      | 01.2016       | 02.2016       | 03.2016       |
| farm_location |              |              |              |               |               |               |
| sweden        | 42           | 41           | 43           | 52            | 51            | 53            |
```

It's a very weird formatting, but that's what is in the excel file. At first the 2 first rows are not even in a multiindex form.

I managed to get it into a multiindex with the code below, but some columns are duplicated (salads_count appears several times for example):

```
arrays = [df.columns.tolist(), df.iloc[0].tolist()]
tuples = list(zip(*arrays))
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuples)
df.columns = index
```

I would like to convert the columns to a multiindex, something like that:

```
|               | salads_count |         |         | carrot_counts |         |         |
|---------------|--------------|---------|---------|---------------|---------|---------|
|               | 01.2016      | 02.2016 | 03.2016 | 01.2016       | 02.2016 | 03.2016 |
| farm_location |              |         |         |               |         |         |
| sweden        | 42           | 41      | 43      | 52            | 51      | 53      |
```

Or even better, like that:

```
|               | 01.2016      |              | 02.2016      |             |   |   |
|---------------|--------------|--------------|--------------|-------------|---|---|
|               | carrot_count | salads_count | carrot_count | salad_count |   |   |
| farm_location |              |              |              |             |   |   |
| sweden        | 52           | 42           | 51           | 41          |   |   |
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best is convert columns to `MultiIndex` in [`read_excel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_excel.html) by parameter `header=[0,1]`:

```
df = pd.read_excel(file, header=[0,1])
```

Then use [`swaplevel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.swaplevel.html) with [`sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html):

```
df = df.swaplevel(0,1, axis=1).sort_index(axis=1, level=0)
```

Comment: Ok, I had tried the header thingy but didn't realise you could pass a list of rows. In your second command, what does `sortt_index` do? It works without and doesn't move my `farm_location`column.

Comment: @Rififi - In my opinion this question is really data dependent, is possible share your sample data in excel? Via gdogs, dropbox... Because really hard to test your format.

Comment: I can't provide the original excel data file, it's confidential. I was asking the `sortindex`question out of curiosity, it works already without.